# Can't push changes to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've added Twilio to my rails app and when I go to push the changes to heroku I'm getting the following error. I've having trouble tracing it back to the issue.

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/twilio-ruby-3.11.5/lib/twilio-ruby/rest/client.rb:142:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/config/initializers/twilio.rb:6:in `new'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/config/initializers/twilio.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:609:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `each'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `block in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:250:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_04f806c2-b1ba-46f8-a554-26485f452fbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Update: In my Twilio.rb (config/initializer) I had copied over some code from Twilio's site.

```
require "twilio-ruby"
```

Once I removed this I was able to get it to push to heroku.

Comment: Did you set up your `account_sid`?

Comment: Yes, I got it working. Thanks for asking though.

Comment: Good news.  You should post whatever you had to fix as an answer to this question - might help someone else in the future that hits the same problem.

Comment: actually i thought it worked but it didn't...